# Скрипт "смена картинки" (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

Есть скрипт для смены двух картинок при наведении мышки

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
        $('img').hover(function() {
            var _this = this,
                images = _this.getAttribute('data').split(',');
                counter = 0;
            this.setAttribute('data-src', this.src);    
            //
            _this.timer = setInterval(function() {
                if(counter > (images.length-1)) {
                    counter = 0;
                }
                _this.src=images[counter];

                counter++;
            }, 500);

        }, function() {
            this.src = this.getAttribute('data-src');    
            clearInterval(this.timer);
        });
    });
</script>

<a href="" class="b-socials__link"><img src="images/icon_social-heart_big.png" data="images/icon_social-heart_big.png, images/icon_social-heart_small.png"' alt=""></a>
```

подскажите, как его поправить, чтобы смена картинок происходила не при наведении мышки. а постоянно?

Comment: к вашему комментарию (я почему-то там не могу оставлять уже комментарии): может быть doctype был не тот прописан? Просто я знаю, что часто из-за него проблемы возникают.

Comment: на странице стоит доктайп html5 <!DOCTYPE HTML>. а из-за какого доктайпа могут быть проблемы?

Comment: @Heidel из-за какого не могу сказать, лучше тестовый вариант с проблемой покажите. А то сидим, гадаем :)

Comment: не могу показать - страница не в сети. но вроде все нормально работает. а с какими доктайпами вообще может быть проблема? и еще по вашему скрипту вопрос хотелось бы задать, который вы здесь приводили http://pastebin.com/7YztgmqC , тоже получается, использовалось много методов hasClass(), removeClass(), addClass(). а, допустим, с использованием одного метода toggleClass() и временного интервала такое нельзя сделать? ну, мне просто интересно, как это все работает)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вместо:

```
$('img').hover(function() {
```

написать:

```
$('img').each(function() {
```

Comment: и убрать вторую анонимную функцию.

Comment: а если не тот скрипт править, а сделать самый простой вариант смены двух картинок, то вот так нормально будет http://jsfiddle.net/GpmtB/ ?

Comment: @Heidel скажем так: слишком перегружено. По сути можно просто поставить изменение css стиля, а переменную с изменяемой картинкой объявить до интервала.

Comment: а объясните, пожалуйста, подробнее, как это сделать?

Comment: давайте я пример приведу: http://pastebin.com/7YztgmqC

Comment: а, понятно, большое спасибо. а в ие такой скрипт будет работать?

Comment: @Heidel ну так вы попробуйте.

Comment: на странице как-то странно срабатывало в ие, попробовала отдельно вынести скрипт в jsfiddle, там в ие всё работает.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function fName() {
    $('img').hover(function() {
        var _this = this,
            images = _this.getAttribute('data').split(',');
            counter = 0;
        this.setAttribute('data-src', this.src);    
        //
        _this.timer = setInterval(function() {
            if(counter > (images.length-1)) {
                counter = 0;
            }
            _this.src=images[counter];

            counter++;
        }, 500);

    }, function() {
        this.src = this.getAttribute('data-src');    
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        fName();
    });
});
```

Дай функции имя и попробуй её просто вызывать заново.